# Running ansible playbooks parallel on same host

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, parallel-processing, ansible

I am trying to run 30 os.commands that runs ansible-playbook on same host in threaded parallel way in a python script. If i run 30 ansible-playbooks in serial way it is doing all 30 jobs. But when i try to run them in parallel way some playbooks do task some does not do tasks. Python is handling the threaded running of playbooks. I think when ansible tries to run multiple ansible-playbook at the same time on same host a conflict occurs. How can i run 30 threaded playboks at the same time on same host.

```
def runOsCommand( systemCommand ):
    print(systemCommand)
    logging.info(" "+systemCommand)
    os.system(systemCommand)

def createProfile( Profile,ProfileDesc ):
    Command= "ansible-playbook create-profile.yml  --extra-vars \"VARIABLE1=" + str(Profile) + " " +  "VARIABLE2=" + str(ProfileDesc) +"\""
    runOsCommand(Command)
    return

class Thread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.threadID = threadID
        self.name = name
        self.counter = counter
    def run(self):
        print "Starting " + self.name
        createProfile(Profile,ProfileDesc)     
        print "Exiting " + self.name

for iter in range(30):
    mythreadx = Thread(iter, "Thread-Datapool-Row-"+str(iter), iter)
    mythreadx.start()
```

Comment: "*some playbooks do task some does not do tasks*" -- you need to do some troubleshooting to find some problems in some parts of your code, or in some configuration setting. I have some ideas of what might be your issue, but I have some doubts if they apply.

Comment: The yml playbook we are calling is same always. We are calling same playbook 30 times in parallel with different arguments. So yml code is always same.

Comment: Now that you explained everything, there is no reason for not getting a correct answer. Let’s sit and wait.

Comment: I have to do the same thing, what was your conclusion ?

Comment: Related to what I just published: [ansible-parallel](https://pypi.org/project/ansible-parallel/) is a tool doing exactly this: running playbooks in parallel.